# Excel 2016 - Offset dynamic height & waterfall chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I've been trying to get a waterfall chart to adjust dynamically but don't appear to be able to get the offset working.  I don't know if it is a limitation with my knowledge, the chart, or the function.

So the code looks like this:

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(Data!$O:$O,MATCH(Dash!$AN$4,Data!$A:$A,0)),0,0,Lookups!$G$9,1)
```

`Lookups!$G$9` is linked to a spinner that will allow switching between `30`, `90`, and `365` days and is multiplying the resultant number by `-1` to come to a negative number for the height of the offset as the most recent entries for the spreadsheet are at the bottom and the dates count backwards.  So the height should be `-30`, `-90`, or `-365`.  I want the chart to change at the click of the spinner, and in my head this works.

Am I doing something incorrectly or is this an excel limitation?

Many thanks in advance for any advice you are able to provide!

Comment: Ok, so I changed the chart type to a line chart and the range changes when I click on the spinner button.  Should I assume that this is a limitation of the waterfall chart type?

Comment: So I managed to solve this, for some reason despite offset being volatile it is not automatically updating the chart when one of the cells that it relies upon for instructions changes.  I added a RAND function and multiplied by 0 in the formula just to get it to refresh, and encapsulated the lot in IFERROR as when the range exceeded the data available it would error but then not fix itself when the range came back inside the data available.  Here is what it ended up looking like:-


=IFERROR(OFFSET(INDEX(Data!$O:$O,MATCH(Dash!$AN$4,Data!$A:$A,0)),0,0,Lookups!$E$9,1)+(RAND()*0),0)

Comment: you may share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. ( :

Comment: Hey there, still getting to grips with how the site works! Do I just copy and paste the answer into the answer box at the bottom? =)

Comment: That shall do.  (  :

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to solve this, for some reason despite offset being volatile it is not automatically updating the chart when one of the cells that it relies upon for instructions changes. I added a RAND function and multiplied by 0 in the formula just to get it to refresh, and encapsulated the lot in IFERROR as when the range exceeded the data available it would error but then not fix itself when the range came back inside the data available. Here is what it ended up looking like:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(INDEX(Data!$O:$O,MATCH(Dash!$AN$4,Data!$A:$A,0)),0,0,Lookups!$E$9,1)+(RAND()*0),0)
```